# Foreach statment only showing 1 record from the database rather than the supposed amount

Tags: php

I am selecting rows from the database. When I print_r it is showing 3 records, but inside my 2nd foreach it's only showing 1 record.

```
      //get productid
        $product = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM bids,orders,products WHERE bids.bids_username=? AND NOW() > products.enddate AND orders.orders_status=0 GROUP BY bids.bids_item ORDER BY bids.bids_amount DESC");
        $product->execute(array($username->username));
        $productid = $product->fetchAll();

        print_R($productid);
        //check if order is in database
        foreach($productid as $product):
            $order = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders_product=? AND orders_username=?");
            $order->execute(array($product->bids_item, $username->username));
            $result = $order->fetchAll();
        endforeach;

        //insert order
        if(!$result):
        $createorder = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(orders_username,orders_product,orders_firstname, orders_lastname, orders_address1, orders_address2, orders_zipcode, orders_city, orders_country, orders_btcaddress, orders_status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        foreach($productid as $product):
        echo  $product->bids_item;
               //get btc address, check it's valid, then if isset run query below
               $createorder->execute(array($username->username, $product->bids_item, $username->firstname, $username->lastname, $username->address1, $username->address2, $username->zipcode, $username->city, $username->country, 'jkjkjk', 0));
               return 1;
        endforeach;
        endif;
```

Whem I echo the bids_item it's only showing 1 result when it should run through all 3 and echo them all. Is there anything in my code that looks wrong?

Comment: You `return 1;` inside the loop after displaying a record, so it won't continue iterating the loop for subsequent records, but will return to the calling code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in your second foreach loop

```
foreach($productid as $product):
    echo  $product->bids_item;
    //get btc address, check it's valid, then if isset run query below
    $createorder->execute(array($username->username, $product->bids_item, $username->firstname, $username->lastname, $username->address1, $username->address2, $username->zipcode, $username->city, $username->country, 'jkjkjk', 0));
   return 1;
endforeach;
```

The return statement causes all execution to stop the first run through. Remove the return statement and it should function as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your second foreach just replace

```
$result[] = $order->fetchAll();
```

You will receive an array. Currently you are overwriting the next value of foreach loop. Please do the same in next foreach, if you want.